# How can I split a long table in a page layout document using Pages app?

Tags: macos, pages

If using Pages as a page layout app, you can continue text from one text box into another.

[image]

I'm looking around for a similar thing for tables. That is, I have a table on one page and I want to continue it on the next page, instead of creating another table and make it look as a continuation of the first.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages allows you to make tables that auto-continue to the next page if the number of rows times row height exceeds the space of the first page. And under Format -> Table you get options to designate 0 or more "header" rows, and the option to Repeat Header Rows on Each Page.

Note that if you want something else to appear on the next page before its section of your table, you could use margin settings, headers/footers, text box insertions, etc.

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted, but I'm not sure you understand my question correctly. "Pages allows you to make tables that auto-continue to the next page if the number of rows times row height exceeds the space of the first page." --- Yes, this is how it works by default when you use Pages as a word processing app. But how make it work when you use it as a page layout app, that is, for example, if you start your document from the "Blank Layout" template?

Comment: Hmm. I'll check that out. You might be right. I still use other tools for page layout, so haven't gone there with Pages. Clarify this: is your goal for the table that its sections on successive pages are (or can be) separated from previous/subsequent table sections by other material?

Comment: You seem to be right that tables don't provide the simple way inserted text boxes may be linked to flow from one to the next across pages. But I *was* able to get a table to continue to the next page in a Blank Layout doc by making the page's bottom margin really large. In a table placed on the first page, if I add enough rows to hit that bottom margin, the table continues on the next page as I think you want. With those big margins, it's still possible to insert/place other elements such as text boxes within the margin's protected areas. Probably works with large footers, too. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what paragraph style is applied to the table. It can have a style applied that has a page break applied to it. Set the style to "Body" and see if that permits the table to flow from one page to the other.